# Scala - Use classes from separate files

Tags: scala

I have a number of different scala files each defining their own class. All of the files are located in the SAME directory. It is my understanding that if they are in the same directory you should not need to worry about packages or imports. However I am trying to compile a file and I'm receiving `not found` errors.

Is there a difference between using classes and objects from different files and can someone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if your files all in the same `package`.

Scala breaks with the Java convention that the folder structure needs to represent the package structure.
So you will get no feedback and or automatic warning when you have file in the wrong package.

## Example

In given example the *files* are located in the *same folder* but belong to different *packages*.

### File view:

`src/main/scala/biz/neumann/foo.scala`

```
package biz.neumann.not_in_example
class Foo
```

`src/main/scala/biz/neumann/bar.scala`

```
package biz.neumann.example
class Bar
```

### Package view

```
biz .neumann .not_in_example .Foo 
             .example        .Bar
```

Comment: Do my files need to be in a package? I currently have not added any of the files to any package. I thought that because they are in the same folder they don't need a package.

Comment: Your `classes` are always in a `package`. Your `files` are always in `folders`.  So files can not be in packages as this is a completely different thing.